# Запятая перед «даже когда»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

Нужна ли в предложении запятая перед "даже когда"?

**А я так и стоял, смотря ему вслед даже когда за ним закрылась дверь в подъезд.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая нужна.

Но вопрос-то интересный. Только ставить его надо не так.
***Можно ли обойтись без запятой?***
И, судя по всему, нельзя, хотя и очень хочется.
Я не отрицаю ничего из сказанного в других ответах. Но они немножко не о том. Они отвечают на вопрос, ***где*** запятая должна стоять, а не ***нужна ли она вообще***. А я просто пытаюсь понять, почему вообще возник такой вопрос.

Понятно, что запятая возможна, хотя бы потому, что придаточное можно считать никак не связанным с деепричастным оборотом. А вот если считать оборот и придаточное некоторым аналогом однородных членов... По смыслу это вполне допустимо, более того, я именно так и воспринимаю (смотреть вслед и уходить - здесь два действия определяемых понятием "когда": ***"я стоял, когда смотрел ему вслед и дверь закрылась"*** ). Но грамматика не дает ни малейшего повода для подобного разбора исходной фразы. Деепричастный оборот невозможно оторвать от грамматического сказуемого. Таким образом, запятая нужна сразу по двум причинам. Придаточное отделить и деепричастный оборот закрыть.

Answer (score 1):

*А я так и стоял, смотря ему вслед,  **даже когда** за ним закрылась дверь в подъезд.*

**Вопрос:** Нужна ли запятая перед "даже когда" в предложении?

**Ответ:** ЗАПЯТАЯ НУЖНА.

**Обоснование:**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным **времени**, **частица ДАЖЕ относится к союзу когда**, деепричастный оборот входит в состав главного предложения.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137

6. Если перед подчинительным союзом стоят усилительные частицы как раз, только, лишь, исключительно и т. п., то перед ними ставится запятая (вопреки интонации, так как при чтении пауза перед ними не делается): Катя вышла из столовой, как раз когда мы шагнули друг к другу через какие-то чемоданы (Кав.); Я эту работу выполню, только если буду свободен (ср.: …если только буду свободен); Он приехал, исключительно чтобы помочь мне.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Смысл фразы такой: **смотрел ему вслед, даже когда дверь за ним закрылась.**

Но именно такое понимание дает не грамматика, а расстановка логических ударений и деление предложения на две интонационные фразы:

***А я так и стоял, смотря ему вслЕд***, // **даже когда** за ним закрылась дверь в подъЕзд.

**Это двухчастная, а не трехчастная  конструкция,** так как мы не обозначаем в устной речи паузу перед деепричастным оборотом, хотя грамматическая запятая там стоит. Это общий принцип построения сложных предложений, когда *младшая* конструкция (обособленный оборот) в части интонации как бы подчиняется *старшей* конструкции (сложному предложению).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в данном предложении должна стоять перед словом "даже". Если частица ДАЖЕ стоит перед союзом в сложноподчиненном предложении, то запятая ставится перед даже, а перед союзом - нет: "Она всегда врала, ДАЖЕ КОГДА правду говорила". Ваше предложение будет выглядеть так:"А я так и стоял, смотря ему вслед, даже когда за ним закрылась дверь в подъезд". К тому же еще "смотря ему вслед" - деепричастный оборот, который обособляется с двух сторон.